# Cakephp retrieve info from database

Tags: php, mysql, database, cakephp

I'm having some problems understanding the connection to the database in CakePHP.

I have a table called user (which was taken from the CakePHP tutorial website) I added another row to the table called "bio" I am able to insert text into the bio but i'm not able to retrieve it. 
I've managed to retrieve all the other rows by:

```
     $name = CakeSession::read("Auth.User.username");
     $mail = CakeSession::read("Auth.User.email");
     $created = CakeSession::read("Auth.User.created");
     $id = CakeSession::read("Auth.User.id");
```

but for some reason it won't work with the bio.

Do I need to add anything to controllers to be able to this? Or is it a variable that I need to set?

Thank you!

Comment: How did you give name 'bio' to a table row? You probably mean, you added a column.

Comment: What is the error you are receiving when you try to retrieve the **bio** column?

Comment: The data you are fetching here are from the `Session` not from database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @sgt BOSE said. Using CakeSession::read("Auth.User") you will get session data of your current logged user.

```
$current_user_data = $this->User->FindById(CakeSession::read("Auth.User.id"));
```

This will return current (logged) user data from database.